# C# | Отличие Border от Rectangle в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Изучаю WPF (IDE Visual Studio). Не могу пока осознать разницу между двумя элементами border и rectangle. Оба элемента имеют свойства по закраске внутренней области и самой границы. Кто знает в чем принципиальная разница, подскажите!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое основное: `Border` может иметь дочерний контрол, `Rectangle` - нет.

Например, вот так можно

```xml
<Border Background="Red">
    <Button Margin="5" Content="Click me!"/>
</Border>
```

А вот так - нет

```xml
<Rectangle Fill="Red">
    <Button Margin="5" Content="Click me!"/><!-- ОШИБКА -->
</Rectangle>
```

В целом, чтобы различать назначение, `Rectangle` предназначен для рисования внутри `Canvas`, а `Border` - для задач дизайна в остальной части интерфейса.