# WPF Как отобразить SVG

Tags: c#, wpf

Задача, которую необходимо выполнить:

Разработать систему, позволяющую автоматически строить блок-схему. Позволять пользователю отдалять и приближать к блокам этой блок-схемы. Отлавливать ивенты клика на отдельные блоки

Пример блок-схемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Идея, которая сразу возникла - обычный bitmap здесь не подходит, т.к. имеет ограниченное количество пикселей, следовательно, не позволит "красиво" отображать все элементы при приближении. Выход из проблемы - создание векторного изображения. Отрисовка на нём (не знаю, пока что, каким образом) блоков и вывод пользователю...в какой-то контрол. Отлов событий клика - координаты, где произошёл клик и проверка, существует ли в этом месте блок

На каком контроле в WPF возможно реализовать эту задачу? Или потребуются дополнительные библиотеки?

Comment: SVG можно сконвертировать в XAML, есть программы-конвертеры. Так же можно рисовать векторной графикой всё что угодно. Есть Canvas и прочие примитивы для рисования на нём - рямоугольники, линии, полигоны, Path как в SVG и т. д.

Comment: Прямоугольник в частности называется Rectangle, либо есть ещё Border. Разницу я объяснял [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1351166/373567).

Comment: Каким тогда способом можно реализовать приближение и отдаление?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128695/Deep-Zoom-for-WPF