# ScrollViewer контролы выходят за рамки границ панели C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть панель Grid В первых Row у меня идет Rectangle он используется как фон.
Далее в последней Row я создаю ScrollViewer с панелью Grid для прокрутки элементов панели, которая содержит в себе другие панели grid. На скриншоте видно что контролы вылазят за границу Rectangle. Подскажите как ограничить контролы, чтобы они были в рамках Rectangle

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <!--Команды-->
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="GridComands" Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="8, 11 ,0,0" Visibility="Visible" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  ClipToBounds="True" Grid.RowSpan="12" Stroke="#EBEBEB" MaxHeight="560" Fill="#FFFFFF" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" Margin="0,9,31,15"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="15,18,0,0" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="15"><Run Text="Команды"/></TextBlock>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Stroke="#EBEBEB" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" Margin="0,10,31,0" />
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="8" ClipToBounds="True">
                <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="27*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <!--Предупреждения-->
                    <Grid x:Name="GridPred" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="CbPred"  IsChecked="{Binding Pred, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="CommandDB" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20,0,0,0" Padding="5,2,0,0"  Background="Transparent" FontSize="14" Content="/pred - предупреждения"/>
                        <Button x:Name="BtnPred" Grid.Column="1" Width="70" Height="30" Grid.Row="0" Margin="200,-0,0,0"  Click="BtnPred_Click"/>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Stroke="#EBEBEB" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" Margin="0,8,31,5" />
                        <Grid x:Name="GridPredPanel" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,8,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="15"><Run Text="Количество предупреждений"/></TextBlock>
                            <TextBox  Padding="5,4,0,0" x:Name="PredCount" Height="30" FontSize="14" BorderBrush="#A8A8A8" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0,51,23" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="20,8,51,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="15"><Run Text="Текст сообщения"/></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <!--Мут-->
                    <Grid x:Name="GridMut" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="CbMut"  IsChecked="{Binding Pred, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="CommandDB" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20,0,0,0" Padding="5,2,0,0"  Background="Transparent" FontSize="14" Content="/mut - мут"/>
                        <Button x:Name="BtnMut" Grid.Column="1" Width="70" Height="30" Grid.Row="0" Margin="200,-0,0,0"  Click="BtnMut_Click"/>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Stroke="#EBEBEB" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" Margin="0,8,31,5" />
                        <Grid x:Name="GridMutPanel" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,8,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="15"><Run Text="Время мута"/></TextBlock>
                            <Grid Margin="5,0,51,23" Grid.Row="1" Height="30" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBox  x:Name="MutBorder" Grid.Column="0" MinHeight="25" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="4" FontSize="14" />
                                <TextBox  x:Name="MutCount" Grid.Column="0" Padding="5,8,0,0" Margin="0,-4,80,6" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" FontSize="14" />
                                <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxMutType"  DataContext="CommandDB" Text="{Binding ComboBoxMutType}" SelectedIndex="0" MaxWidth="60" Padding="12,5,0,0" Margin="220,0,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"><Run Text="мин"/></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"><Run Text="часы"/></TextBlock>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock Margin="20,8,51,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="15"><Run Text="Текст сообщения"/></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <!--Thanks-->
                    <Grid x:Name="GridThanks" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="CbThanks" IsChecked="{Binding Pred, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="CommandDB" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20,0,0,0" Padding="5,2,0,0"  Background="Transparent" FontSize="14" Content="/thanks - благодарность"/>
                        <Button x:Name="BtnThanks" Grid.Column="1" Width="70" Height="30" Grid.Row="0" Margin="200,-0,0,0"  Click="BtnThanks_Click"/>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Stroke="#EBEBEB" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" Margin="0,8,31,5" />
                        <Grid x:Name="GridThanksPanel" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Margin="20,8,51,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="15"><Run Text="Текст сообщения"/></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <!--Complaint-->
                    <Grid x:Name="GridComplaint" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="CbComplaint"  IsChecked="{Binding Pred, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="CommandDB" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20,0,0,0" Padding="5,2,0,0"  Background="Transparent" FontSize="14" Content="/compl - система жалоб"/>
                        <Button x:Name="BtnComplaint" Grid.Column="1" Width="70" Height="30" Grid.Row="0" Margin="200,-0,0,0"  Click="BtnComplaint_Click"/>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Stroke="#EBEBEB" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" Margin="0,8,31,5" />
                        <Grid x:Name="GridComplaintPanel" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Margin="20,8,51,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="15"><Run Text="Текст сообщения"/></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,8,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="15"><Run Text="После скольки жалоб уведомлять"/></TextBlock>
                            <TextBox Padding="5,4,0,0" x:Name="ComplaintCount" Height="30" FontSize="14" BorderBrush="#A8A8A8" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0,51,23" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>
                    <!--Конец коменд-->
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: 1. Зачем вам тут `Rectangle`, если все то, для чего вы их используете, можно реализовать простыми `Border`? 2. Дайте полноценный, самодостаточный пример, который можно скопировать, вставить, и увидеть проблему, ибо сейчас это просто пустые прямоугольники с надписью "Команды" сверху.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ https://wdho.ru/b4d6ea4 мини проект на основе вопроса. Как `Border` в этой ситуации указать не совсем понимаю, так как у меня Rectangle в одной строке grid, потом идет надпись и еще одна линия и только потом идёт прокрутка с панелями которые должны внутри Rectangle быть. Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1351166/373567

Comment: Не, так не пойдет. Отредактируйте вопрос, дополнив XAML нужными данными "затычками", а то ради такой мелочи, качать непойми что, непойми от куда, потом искать там нужное, разбираться со всеми связями... Оно мне надо? Тут в ваших интересах донести все нужное, не в моих.

Comment: @aepot немного не то, у меня в примере Rectangle идет как фон над всеми панелями как фон. И у меня проблема с тем что ScrollViewer вылазит за границы Rectangle, будь Border, было бы точно также

Comment: Засуньте скролл внутрь бордера в разметке. Не надо отступов выдумывать будет. А обрезать углы вроде через ClipToBounds можно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ понял, исправил код. Удалил все что не касается вопроса в коде

Comment: @aepot `Засуньте скролл внутрь бордера в разметке.` от этого ничего не изменится, только что сменю  
Rectangle на  Border. 
`ClipToBounds` Почему то не обрезает уже почти везде поставил это

Comment: У меня Grid который в ScrollViewer при добавление контролов, растет в высоту и поэтому  `ClipToBounds` не работает. И пытаясь установить фиксированный размер, ничего с этого не выходит.

Comment: Ваша основная проблема в том, что вы нарисовали полустатичный прямоугольник, который отделен от всего, отделен от контента, ему еще и `Margin` задали, что уменьшило его основные размеры по сравнению с контентом. Вот я подкрасил ваши контролы, и вывел прямоугольник на передний план для наглядности, получил [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvnxS.png). Если уберу у прямоугольника `MaxHeight="560"` и `Margin="0,9,31,15"`, верну цвета, то получу [то, чего вы добиваетесь](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNs4B.png).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да это то что нужно. Если я убираю Margin, то местоположение теряется у в прямоугольника. А он выравнен при помощи margin с другой панелью слева. 
` Если уберу у прямоугольника MaxHeight="560" и Margin="0,9,31,15"` я сделал также и у меня прямоугольник занял всю панель, до низа и справа. Не совсем понял как вы сделали сохранив расположение прямоугольника

Comment: Вот вам пример с [Border](https://pastebin.com/4rN5r4Dk), самая простейшая разметка, результат которой будет [такой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GoP6.png), копию делать вашей не стал, но чисто суть думаю уловите. `то местоположение теряется` - я не вижу в вашей разметке других панелей, или чего либо еще, что может с этим конфликтовать. Повторю свои действия: 1. Скопировал ваш код. 2. Добавил главной сетке `Margin="10"` чтоб видно было рамки, и также удалил то, о чем писал выше ([выделил для наглядности](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSFAe.png)). 3. [Запустил](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cujPb.png).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ верно других панелей в примере нету, спасибо за примеры, кажется мне надо весь контент обернуть в скрол. Попробовал ваш пример со скриншота вышло совсем по другому https://skr.sh/sJuPGXjdPFn прямоугольник оказался не над командами-выше всего контента. А внутри той grid где его указал. И Grid растёт по прежнему https://skr.sh/vJuSNOMMMef как я могу ограничить  панель, чтобы он была фиксированного размера? В вашем примере с Border, вы использовали StackPanel, у меня grid потому что как на видео показал, я расположение элементов расставляю

Comment: @EvgeniyZ сделал как здесь https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSFAe.png у меня ScrollViewer пропал, прямоугольник фиксированного размера, но ScrollViewer не отображается

Comment: Значит у вас в проекте есть что-то еще, что дает такой эффект. Создайте пустой WPF проект, вставьте туда разметку из вопроса, проделайте действия которые я вам сказал, получите то, что надо. Получив нужное, добавляйте из основного проекта по немногу остальное, и смотрите на результат. Я как видите, воспроизвести не могу эту проблему. И да, повторюсь - это костыли, используйте правильную разметку, используйте `Border`. `я расположение элементов расставляю` - В моем примере `StackPanel` для того, чтобы каждая "команда" шла друг под другом, а что внутри самого блока команды, это без разницы.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ понял, спасибо вам за советы. Как освобожусь попробую в пустом проекте получить нужный результат

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как как писали с примером про `Border` Главную Grid обернул в него, а внутри в разметке уже `ScrollViewer` поставил там где нужно. Без отступов лишних и т.п, разметив в `Border` расположение выставив. Теперь работает как надо, спасибо большое за помощь)